# Impurity scattering

Tags: condensed-matter, temperature, scattering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Impurity scattering temperature dependence](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45634/impurity-scattering-temperature-dependence)

Is there any temperature dependence of relaxation time in impurity scattering of conducting electrons? It seems to me that there is none. But, some people claim that there is.

So if you could explain, how temperature dependence comes into play?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45634/2451

Comment: Please don't re-post simply because you didn't get answers for an existing question. There are [way to draw more attention to the existing question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions), and these are preferred.